# Weierstrass Theorem in Optimization

Tags: optimization

Weierstrass Theorem states that any bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence.

I did that in my maths course and understood it completely. But when I was learning optimization techniques in economics, the definition by the book Sundaram was tweaked slightly to make it fit into the understanding of optimization. It goes like this - (see Figure 1)

If you read it, it is saying just what original theorem said. The only difference is that, instead of starting off with a bounded sequence and reaching the conclusion that it will have convergent subsequence, it started off with a convergent subsequence (by assuming Compact set) and reached the conclusion that it should be bounded. It makes sense right? It did to me too until I found a result on compact set, stated on the same book. (See figure 2)

This redefining of the theorem made it a circular definition - if a set can only be compact if n only if it is bounded then by assuming Compactness in redefinition we implicitly assumed boundedness.

So, my question is please tell me where am I going wrong. Have I understood the redefinition incorrectly or missed so point?

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: As a matter of writing style, may I suggest that you should perhaps avoid the excessive use of the pronoun "it", whose referent is extremely unclear, especially in the second and third paragraphs.

Comment: I don't see what you consider circular here.

Comment: Compactness needs boundedness and closed bounded sequence is compact. If the 'let us consider the compact set' took care of the closed and bounded set (already a theorem [1.21] which established their relationship), then concluding it with the fact that the set will have a maximum and minimum is obvious. This redefinition took away the energy of the original Weierstrass Theorem. @Michael Greinecker

Answer (score 4):

What the book calls the "Weierstrass Theorem" is more commonly known as the [**Extreme Value Theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem), which states that a continuous function defined on a compact domain attains a maximum and a minimum.

[A common proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Proof_of_the_extreme_value_theorem) of this theorem involves the use of the [**Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), which you learned in your math course, and which says every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence.

So the two theorems are actually different, albeit related, statements.